# Directx visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, directx

Yesterday I started to learn how to use directx. I used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms920749.aspx) tutorial.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
namespace _0005_directx_creating_a_device
{
    public class CreateDevice : Form
    {
        Device device = null;

    

    public CreateDevice()
        {
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
            this.Text = "D3D Tutorial 01: CreateDevice";
        }
        public bool InitializeGraphics()
        {
            try
            {
                PresentParameters presentParams = new PresentParameters();
                presentParams.Windowed = true;
                presentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
                device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, this, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, presentParams);
                return true;
            }
            catch (DirectXException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            using (CreateDevice frm = new CreateDevice())
            {
                if (!frm.InitializeGraphics())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nem sikerült elindítani a DirectX-et!");
                    return;
                }
                frm.Show();
                //
                while(frm.Created)
                {
                    frm.Render();
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
        }
        private void Render()
        {
            if (device == null)
                return;
            device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 1.0f, 0);
            device.BeginScene();
            device.EndScene();
            device.Present();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I try to run this program, the console shows up than nothing happens. I linked every reference. I use windows 10 and Visual studio 2015. Any idea why it doesn't do anything ?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like [Managed DirectX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX#.NET_Framework), an API that died over ten years ago. It's successor ([XNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)) is also dead. Look at something like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 APIs which haven't been updated in a decade. They were created for .NET 1.1 and are not compatible with .NET 4.x.

For C# Direct3D development you should use SlimDX, SharpDX, MonoGame, or a commercial engine like Unity instead.

> For C# Direct2D/DirectWrite, consider using [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/win2d).

See [DirectX and .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out :)